# How do I get the the query parameters of the url of the web-app?

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-web

I am planning to create an online game that uses some kind of lobby system. I want the host to be able to create an invite link `http://randomgame.io/join?code=1234abcd`.

How do I get the `code` parameter of the URL so that I can show content based on this code?

Any help is much appreciated :D

Edit:

I can get the URL by using `Uri.base` but the problem now is that I can't enter any query parameters into the url because they get instantly removed.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html

Answer (score 2):

With [this](https://pub.dev/packages/window_location_href) package you can get current link from users browser, using function `getHref()`. So the final code could look like this:

```
import 'package:window_location_href/window_location_href.dart';

final String url = getHref();
Uri uri = new Uri.dataFromString(url);
String codeParam = uri.queryParameters['code'];
```

Comment: The problem that I have is that the query parameters disappear from the URL when entering them into the address bar

Comment: Thats because you are probably using named routes, so when using named routes, the url is overwritten